# MeanJS vs SailsJS page loading speed

Tags: sails.js, meanjs

I have tried both meanjs and sailsjs.

I have yet deployed my meanjs app into heroku however, it seems that meanJS is slow when I tried to preview it in codio (cloudIDE). In contrast, SailsJS is blazing fast. Is this only a problem during development? Will I get to see the speed of SailsJS once I deployed my MEANJS app onto heroku? Because right now it's taking me >1 second for the page to load, compared to almost instantaneously in SailsJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just recently used a Mac for my web development, and I've realised that MEANJS pages loads almost instantaneously when developing on my local environment. I guess the problem lies on the cloudIDE itself.